# Manual Windows 10 installation on Macbook Pro mid 2014 using unetbootin

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, partition, mojave

Just some some context before i ask my actual question.

I know my mac is older so I have been using a USB to use bootcamp.

I have tried installing Windows 10 using the Bootcamp assistant multiple times. The errors that i get are "Status: Disk Partitioning..." once the bootcamp assistant finishes. So I then create my own FAT32 style partition using disk utility. Also have cleared out time machine so it does not manually backup. Once i start the computer in EFI mode or windows i get through to the formatting of the partition but receive this error: "Windows detected that the EFI system partition was formatted as NTFS. Format the EFI System partition as FAT32 and restart installation". So I have tried that reformatting it.

Now I have given up using the bootcamp assistant and tried moving on to unetbootin. Does anyone know if when using unetbootin you need to use a USB 2.0.

Also it has to be greater than 8gb since the iso file + the windows support software is greater than 8gb total.

If anyone has suggestions or answers they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Z

Comment: just to make it clear, you want to install windows on the internal drive, not usb, right?

Comment: yes, i want to be able to run Both MacOS and Windows 10 using dual boot

Comment: I'd suggest borrowing a windows computer for a minute and making the installer drive using mediacreationtool.exe